# 'prelinking' JSPs from different directory

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

We have a setup where we can have customer specific JSP files overriding default JSP files in our service. On deployment the custom JSP files are copied from a customer directory and overwrites default JSP files.

This is bad for development though, as we cannot develop inplace, but have to wait for a JSP-deploy target to run before we can reload in the browser.

I've been thinking of somehow 'prelinking' JSP files when developing, meaning that the JSP servlet should first try to load a given JSP path, says /component/test.jsp from /customer/component/test.jsp, and if not load it from the default location.

I can do this easily with a servlet filter, but this doesn't work with jsp includes, and I believe also any forwards done by frameworks such as struts etc, which uses the request dispatcher.

I think it would be solvable by extending Tomcat/Jaspers JspServlet class, but I was hoping there's a simpler (maybe standards compliant) way?

Answer (score 0):

how about put a nginx/apache in front of tomcat? in the ngnix, when a request comes, it first check whether `/customer/component/test.jsp` exists, 
if exists forward request to tomcat with url:

> http://example.com/customer/component/test.jsp

otherwise

> http://example.com/customer/component/test.jsp

Comment: This would work, but I am looking for a servlet container-only solution.